# Vim - How to move the result of a search to the beginning of the file?

Tags: search, vim

I want to search some text and move the entire line where the text belongs to the beginning of the file. Just that.

Comment: We can clean up our comments here now.

Comment: +1 because I learned about the :g/.../m0 thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about the simple move command?

```
:g/^C/m0
:g/^B/m0
:g/^A/m0
```

Comment: There are lots of tricks you can do with m, like moving things to x line, or end of file... Running it twice will even reverse the ordering of the moved lines.

Answer (score 2):

:g/regex/norm dd1Gp

Comment: I must add that this is what I want: :g/regex/norm dd1GP (so it is moved above the first line. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what I'm gonna suggest is a primitive answer as primitive it can get. But nothing else springs to mind currently.

```
:g/A ... some text not including A, B or C.../d
```

(will tell you how many lines it has yanked)

and then you go to the beginning of the file and, for example

```
5P
```

Although, if cases are as simple as this, maybe sorting lines by first letter .... I've never done anything similar but look for older questions.